# Accessing remote mysql instance for replica set creation

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I'm trying to create a replica set. I have mysql running on the server which will act as my master. However, I'm unable to access that server instance remotely.

I have tried all possible configurations. My my.cnf file is following:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

#
# * IMPORTANT
#   If you make changes to these settings and your system uses apparmor, you may
#   also need to also adjust /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.
#
log-bin         =mysql-bin
server-id       =10001

user            = mysql
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0


#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
```

When I'm logged into my server (through ssh) and can successfully log in using following command:

```
mysql -uroot-p test
```

However, when I try to execute following command from another machine:

```
mysql -h <serverip> -uroot -p test
```

I receive following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'<someip>' (using password: YES)
```

Funny part is that `<ip2>` mentioned in the above line isn't my local ip or server ip to which I'm trying to connect.

I must have wasted around 20 hours already trying to resolve this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'' (using password: YES)

This error says root user from remote machine dont have permission to access Mysql.

Create another user and give rights on specific databases which you want to access remotely.

```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%'
       IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some_characters'  
       WITH GRANT OPTION;
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html